# listview highlight first row only

Tags: android, listview

hello guys i have a list that i want to highlight only the first row in it but the problem is that the first row 
(it's the pre last row) of the unseen rows (becomes visible after scrolling) is also being highlighted, and when i scroll too quickly the second and the last row get highlighted
here's my adapter please help

```
 public class ValueItemsListArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ValueItem> {

private final Activity context;
private final ArrayList<ValueItem> mValueItem;
int listHeight;
ListView lv;
boolean multiOwner;
boolean containRisk;

//private boolean fillScreen;
public ValueItemsListArrayAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<ValueItem> mValueItem, boolean multiOwner,boolean containRisk) {
    super(context, R.layout.result_list_item, mValueItem);
    this.context = context;
    this.mValueItem = mValueItem;
    lv = (ListView) context.findViewById(R.id.valueslist);
    this.multiOwner = multiOwner;
    this.containRisk = containRisk;
    //listHeight=lv.getHeight();
    //this.fillScreen=fillScreen;
}
// static to save the reference to the outer class and to avoid access to
// any members of the containing class

private class ViewHolder {
    public TextView titleTextView, valueTextView;
    public View row;
    public ImageView icon;
    public LinearLayout llResult;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // ViewHolder will buffer the assess to the individual fields of the row layout

    final ViewHolder holder;
    // Recycle existing view if passed as parameter
    // This will save memory and time on Android
    // This only works if the base layout for all classes are the same
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.result_list_item, null, true);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.titleTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.result_title);
        holder.llResult = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.llResult);

        holder.valueTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.result_value);
        holder.row = rowView.findViewById(R.id.row);
        holder.icon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.many_owner_icon);
        ViewFont.setListRowTextResizing(rowView, context);


        rowView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    //String s=mValueItem.get(position).getTitle();
    //  int x=holder.titleTextView.getHeight();
    holder.titleTextView.setText(mValueItem.get(position).getTitle());
    if (multiOwner && mValueItem.get(position).getTitle().equals(Plate.getOwnerNameTitle())) {
        //rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        holder.titleTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(57, 113, 67));
        holder.valueTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(57, 113, 67));
        holder.icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (containRisk && position == 0) {
            holder.llResult.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.car_risk);
        }


    } else {
        holder.valueTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        holder.titleTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        holder.icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (containRisk && position == 0) {
            holder.llResult.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            holder.icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.car_risk);
        }
        Log.wtf("position",""+position);
    }

    holder.valueTextView.setText(mValueItem.get(position).getValue());
    //holder.valueTextView.setTextColor(mValueItem.get(position).getColor());
    if (mValueItem.get(position).getBackground() != 0)
        holder.row.setBackgroundResource(mValueItem.get(position).getBackground());
    else
        holder.row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.result_text);

    Log.d("pos",""+position);

    return rowView;


}


}
```

Comment: You want to highlight only one row?

Comment: yes only row the first one (of position ==0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only check for the position for first row only in your getView Method.

```
if (position != 0)
         holder.row.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    else
        holder.row.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: Where have you changed it ? Please show your edited code.

Comment: exactly where it was written

Comment: Make sure you get the correct background color from your `mValueItem` @eshteghelcompany

Comment: by the way this isn't the case, the problem is the highlighting in RED

Comment: Then its totally simple @eshteghelcompany Check out i have updated my code. It must work this way. It might not be working because of too many if conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (position != 0)
    holder.row.setBackgroundResource(mValueItem.get(position).getBackground());
else
    holder.row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.result_text);
```

put above code as follows(see the comment)

```
if (rowView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.result_list_item, null, true);

    holder = new ViewHolder();

    holder.titleTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.result_title);
    holder.llResult = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.llResult);

    holder.valueTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.result_value);
    holder.row = rowView.findViewById(R.id.row);
    holder.icon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.many_owner_icon);
    ViewFont.setListRowTextResizing(rowView, context);

    //put above code here

    rowView.setTag(holder);
}
```

Comment: you mean like this if (rowView == null) {
            if (mValueItem.get(position).getBackground() != 0)
                holder.row.setBackgroundResource(mValueItem.get(position).getBackground());
            else
                holder.row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.result_text);
            rowView.setTag(holder);
        }

Comment: @eshteghelcompany yes correct along with your complete code. see my edit

Comment: @eshteghelcompany what's the problem now? also c hange it to `if (position != 0)`

Comment: here is what i want to change if (containRisk && position == 0) {
                holder.llResult.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                holder.icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.car_risk);
            }

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of default behaviour of listview, As you used holder it always reuse view. To make it happen on only first row here you go:

```
if (multiOwner && mValueItem.get(position).getTitle().equals(Plate.getOwnerNameTitle())) {
    //rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    holder.titleTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(57, 113, 67));
    holder.valueTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(57, 113, 67));
    holder.icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (containRisk && position == 0) {
        holder.llResult.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.car_risk);
    }else{

       // Set the default color which you want or which you already set to your row add your else part here and your are done

       holder.llResult.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
     }


} else {
    holder.valueTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    holder.titleTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    holder.icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (containRisk && position == 0) {
        holder.llResult.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        holder.icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.car_risk);
    }else{
      // Set the default color which you want or which you already set to your row add your else part here and your are done

       holder.llResult.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
     }
    Log.wtf("position",""+position);
}
```

Comment: @eshteghelcompany : Highlight your code where you are changing background

Comment: @eshteghelcompany : What's the issue are you getting now?

Comment: @eshteghelcompany : tell me where exactly are you changing background of your row?

Comment: if (containRisk && position == 0) {
                holder.llResult.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                holder.icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.car_risk);
            }

Comment: @eshteghelcompany : I meant if you want selected you are setting RED color right? and if you don't want what will be the defualt color?

Comment: no the list is of 10 rows the visible are 8, so the ones being highlighted are row 0 and row 8

Comment: @eshteghelcompany : Ok great, Exactly there just put else codition at both places and set defualt color which you want and you will be done, Check my updated answer

Comment: @eshteghelcompany : yeah I got it, Just add else condition and set your default color over there